# concurrent read and write performance

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We are running a cassandra 2-node cluster .
The following is the latency stat for reads or writes when executed independently :

```
99% write avg write latency 99% read avg read latency GC time
545       .227                2816   1.793            2400
```

However,the total read time for the same batch set is almost 3 times worse when performing read and write in parallel(write latencies being almost unaffected).

```
99% read avg read latency GC time
 4055      1.955           6851
```

There is not compaction recorded on the application keyspace - though we could see compaction on the system and system_schema tablespaces.
What may be causing the sizeable jump in read timings for the same sample set - when writes happen concurrent to read?
Another point to mention is that the bloom filter false positives is always 0 - which seems to indicate bloom filters are being used effectively.
Any pointers to investigate is appreciated.

Comment: Can you include table stats from each run? Theres lots of possibilities, one being key cache invalidation leading to more cache misses.

Comment: What is the key metric to monitor for key cache effectiveness?Also,is compaction of system keyspaces a point to worry - considering there is no compaction of the application keyspace.

Comment: `nodetool info` will give you info on keycache. System keyspace compactions shouldnt be a point of worry. There isnt enough information here to give anything but blanket ideas on places to look though - its definitely not expected and I would guess is GC related (which can be result of keycache, data model, heap settings etc). Make sure you have no wide partitions (`nodetool tablestats` and check max partition size). Check for number of tombstones on reads (also in tablestats). How big is heap? How much memory on system?